# Getting rid of maxpooling layer causes running cuda out memory error pytorch

Tags: machine-learning, python, deep-learning, computer-vision, pytorch

Video card: gtx1070ti 8Gb, batchsize 64.
I had such UNET with resnet152 as encoder wich worket pretty fine:

```
class UNetResNet(nn.Module):

def __init__(self, encoder_depth, num_classes, num_filters=32, dropout_2d=0.2,
             pretrained=False, is_deconv=False):
    super().__init__()
    self.num_classes = num_classes
    self.dropout_2d = dropout_2d

    if encoder_depth == 34:
        self.encoder = torchvision.models.resnet34(pretrained=pretrained)
        bottom_channel_nr = 512
    elif encoder_depth == 101:
        self.encoder = torchvision.models.resnet101(pretrained=pretrained)
        bottom_channel_nr = 2048
    elif encoder_depth == 152:
        self.encoder = torchvision.models.resnet152(pretrained=pretrained)
        bottom_channel_nr = 2048

    else:
        raise NotImplementedError('only 34, 101, 152 version of Resnet are implemented')

    self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)

    self.relu = nn.ReLU(inplace=True)

    self.conv1 = nn.Sequential(self.encoder.conv1,
                               self.encoder.bn1,
                               self.encoder.relu,
                               self.pool) #from that pool layer I would like to get rid off

    self.conv2 = self.encoder.layer1
    self.conv3 = self.encoder.layer2
    self.conv4 = self.encoder.layer3
    self.conv5 = self.encoder.layer4
    self.center = DecoderCenter(bottom_channel_nr, num_filters * 8 *2, num_filters * 8, False)

    self.dec5 =  DecoderBlockV(bottom_channel_nr + num_filters * 8, num_filters * 8 * 2, num_filters * 8,   is_deconv)
    self.dec4 = DecoderBlockV(bottom_channel_nr // 2 + num_filters * 8, num_filters * 8 * 2, num_filters * 8, is_deconv)
    self.dec3 = DecoderBlockV(bottom_channel_nr // 4 + num_filters * 8, num_filters * 4 * 2, num_filters * 2, is_deconv)
    self.dec2 = DecoderBlockV(bottom_channel_nr // 8 + num_filters * 2, num_filters * 2 * 2, num_filters * 2 * 2,
                               is_deconv)
    self.dec1 = DecoderBlockV(num_filters * 2 * 2, num_filters * 2 * 2, num_filters, is_deconv)
    self.dec0 = ConvRelu(num_filters, num_filters)
    self.final = nn.Conv2d(num_filters, num_classes, kernel_size=1)

def forward(self, x):
    conv1 = self.conv1(x)
    conv2 = self.conv2(conv1)
    conv3 = self.conv3(conv2)
    conv4 = self.conv4(conv3)
    conv5 = self.conv5(conv4) 
    center = self.center(conv5)
    dec5 = self.dec5(torch.cat([center, conv5], 1))
    dec4 = self.dec4(torch.cat([dec5, conv4], 1))
    dec3 = self.dec3(torch.cat([dec4, conv3], 1))
    dec2 = self.dec2(torch.cat([dec3, conv2], 1))
    dec1 = self.dec1(dec2)
    dec0 = self.dec0(dec1)

    return self.final(F.dropout2d(dec0, p=self.dropout_2d))
# blocks
    class DecoderBlockV(nn.Module):
        def __init__(self, in_channels, middle_channels, out_channels, is_deconv=True):
            super(DecoderBlockV2, self).__init__()
            self.in_channels = in_channels

            if is_deconv:
                self.block = nn.Sequential(
                    ConvRelu(in_channels, middle_channels),
                    nn.ConvTranspose2d(middle_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=4, stride=2,
                                       padding=1),
                    nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels),
                    nn.ReLU(inplace=True)

                )
            else:
                self.block = nn.Sequential(
                    nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2, mode='bilinear'),
                    ConvRelu(in_channels, middle_channels),
                    ConvRelu(middle_channels, out_channels),
                )

        def forward(self, x):
            return self.block(x)



class DecoderCenter(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, middle_channels, out_channels, is_deconv=True):
        super(DecoderCenter, self).__init__()
        self.in_channels = in_channels


        if is_deconv:
            """
                Paramaters for Deconvolution were chosen to avoid artifacts, following
                link https://distill.pub/2016/deconv-checkerboard/
            """

            self.block = nn.Sequential(
                ConvRelu(in_channels, middle_channels),
                nn.ConvTranspose2d(middle_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=4, stride=2,
                                   padding=1),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels), 
                nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
            )
        else:
            self.block = nn.Sequential(
                ConvRelu(in_channels, middle_channels),
                ConvRelu(middle_channels, out_channels)

            )

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.block(x)
```

Then I edited my class looks to make it work without pooling layer:

```
class UNetResNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, encoder_depth, num_classes, num_filters=32, dropout_2d=0.2,
                 pretrained=False, is_deconv=False):
        super().__init__()
        self.num_classes = num_classes
        self.dropout_2d = dropout_2d

        if encoder_depth == 34:
            self.encoder = torchvision.models.resnet34(pretrained=pretrained)
            bottom_channel_nr = 512
        elif encoder_depth == 101:
            self.encoder = torchvision.models.resnet101(pretrained=pretrained)
            bottom_channel_nr = 2048
        elif encoder_depth == 152:
            self.encoder = torchvision.models.resnet152(pretrained=pretrained)
            bottom_channel_nr = 2048
        else:
            raise NotImplementedError('only 34, 101, 152 version of Resnet are implemented')

        self.relu = nn.ReLU(inplace=True)

        self.input_adjust = nn.Sequential(self.encoder.conv1,
                                          self.encoder.bn1,
                                          self.encoder.relu)

        self.conv1 = self.encoder.layer1
        self.conv2 = self.encoder.layer2
        self.conv3 = self.encoder.layer3
        self.conv4 = self.encoder.layer4

        self.dec4 = DecoderBlockV(bottom_channel_nr, num_filters * 8 * 2, num_filters * 8, is_deconv)
        self.dec3 = DecoderBlockV(bottom_channel_nr // 2 + num_filters * 8, num_filters * 8 * 2, num_filters * 8,    is_deconv)
        self.dec2 = DecoderBlockV(bottom_channel_nr // 4 + num_filters * 8, num_filters * 4 * 2, num_filters * 2,    is_deconv)
        self.dec1 = DecoderBlockV(bottom_channel_nr // 8 + num_filters * 2, num_filters * 2 * 2, num_filters * 2 * 2,is_deconv)
        self.final = nn.Conv2d(num_filters * 2 * 2, num_classes, kernel_size=1)

    def forward(self, x):
        input_adjust = self.input_adjust(x)
        conv1 = self.conv1(input_adjust)
        conv2 = self.conv2(conv1)
        conv3 = self.conv3(conv2)
        center = self.conv4(conv3)
        dec4 = self.dec4(center) #now without centblock
        dec3 = self.dec3(torch.cat([dec4, conv3], 1))
        dec2 = self.dec2(torch.cat([dec3, conv2], 1))
        dec1 = F.dropout2d(self.dec1(torch.cat([dec2, conv1], 1)), p=self.dropout_2d)
        return self.final(dec1)
```

is_deconv - in both cases True. After changing it stop to work with batchsize 64, only with with size of 16 or with batchsize 64 but with resnet16 only - otherwise out of cuda memory. What am I doing wrong?

Full stack of error:

```
~/Desktop/ml/salt/open-solution-salt-identification-master/common_blocks/unet_models.py in forward(self, x)
    418         conv1 = self.conv1(input_adjust)
    419         conv2 = self.conv2(conv1)
--> 420         conv3 = self.conv3(conv2)
    421         center = self.conv4(conv3)
    422         dec4 = self.dec4(center)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in __call__(self, *input, **kwargs)
    355             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    356         else:
--> 357             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    358         for hook in self._forward_hooks.values():
    359             hook_result = hook(self, input, result)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/container.py in forward(self, input)
     65     def forward(self, input):
     66         for module in self._modules.values():
---> 67             input = module(input)
     68         return input
     69 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in __call__(self, *input, **kwargs)
    355             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    356         else:
--> 357             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    358         for hook in self._forward_hooks.values():
    359             hook_result = hook(self, input, result)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torchvision-0.2.0-py3.6.egg/torchvision/models/resnet.py in forward(self, x)
     79 
     80         out = self.conv2(out)
---> 81         out = self.bn2(out)
     82         out = self.relu(out)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really familiar with pytorch (I only know keras) so I'm not really sure. But here's some possible reasons for memory error:

1. **The garbage collector isn't working properly** so the neural network models you've created while doing trial and error are just filling up in the memory and aren't being cleared. This can occur when you are using a notebook and doing modifications to the NN model there. In keras, you can [add a few lines of codes](http://forums.fast.ai/t/how-could-i-release-gpu-memory-of-keras/2023/17) to manually free up the GPU memory.
2. **Removing the maxpooling layer makes the model too large** for the memory to handle. Basically, the function of the maxpooling layer is to pick only the maximum values produced by the previous convolution layers. By removing the maxpooling layer, you tell the model to use all the output produced by the previous convolution layers. It could be that these are in hundreds of millions VS only a few thousands when only the maximum values are used with the maxpooling layer.

Comment: Removing the maxpooling layer makes the model too large - nice idea, sounds as really good explanation. But this is might something else, because I believe it worked